# while orientation changing memory is increasing

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, memory-management

sorry to asking basic question.In my viewcontroller memory is going up when  i rotate my device to prevent that I modified all my IBOutlets with @property and @synthesize even that also not working still my allocation are going peak i dont know what mistake i did in didrotate method I provided my code below.Here i am just modifying  my images and frames for my IBOutlets.Is there  any wrong in the below provided code?

```
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation{
            if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation)){
                for(UIImageView *thumbImage in [tableSupportView subviews]){
                        UIImage *tempImage=[bookListDataSource bookAtIndex:thumbnilIndex].titleImage;
                        CGFloat thumbnilHeight=95*((float) tempImage.size.height/tempImage.size.width);
                        thumbImage.frame=CGRectMake(thumbnilIndex*125, (205-thumbnilHeight)/2, 95, thumbnilHeight);
                        thumbnilIndex++;
                }
                self.myoutlets.frame=cgrect(frames according to criteria);
                NSString *detailImagePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"details_bg_nb" ofType:@"png"];
                UIImage *detailImage=[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:detailImagePath];
                UIColor *bookDetailViewColor=[[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:detailImage];
                self.bookDetailView.backgroundColor=bookDetailViewColor;
                [bookDetailViewColor release];
                [detailImage release];
                NSString *listBGImagePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"list_bg_nb" ofType:@"png"];
                UIImage *listBGImage=[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:listBGImagePath];
                UIColor *listHeaderContainerViewColor=[[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:listBGImage];
                self.listHeaderContainerView.backgroundColor=listHeaderContainerViewColor;
                [listHeaderContainerViewColor release];
                [listBGImagePath release];

                NSString *listBandPath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"listband_potrait" ofType:@"png"];
                UIImage *listBand=[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:listBandPath];
                self.categoryBrandingImageView.image=listBand;
                [listBand release];
            }else {
                NSUInteger thumbnilIndex=0;
                NSUInteger numberOfBooks=[bookListDataSource numberOfBooks];
                for(UIImageView *thumbImage in [tableSupportView subviews]){
                        UIImage *tempImage=[bookListDataSource bookAtIndex:thumbnilIndex].titleImage;
                        CGFloat thumbnilHeight=85*((float) tempImage.size.height/tempImage.size.width);
                        thumbImage.frame=CGRectMake(thumbnilIndex*115, (CGRectGetHeight(tableSupportView.frame)-thumbnilHeight)/2.0, 85, thumbnilHeight);
                        thumbnilIndex++;
                    }
                }
            self.myoutlets.frame=cgrectmake(my custom frame);
                NSString *detailImagePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"landscape_details_bg_nb" ofType:@"png"];
                UIImage *detailImage=[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:detailImagePath];
                UIColor *bookDetailViewColor=[[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:detailImage];
                self.bookDetailView.backgroundColor=bookDetailViewColor;
                [bookDetailViewColor release];
                [detailImage release];

                NSString *listBGImagePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"landscape_list_bg_nb" ofType:@"png"];
                UIImage *listBGImage=[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:listBGImagePath];
                UIColor *listHeaderContainerViewColor=[[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:listBGImage];
                self.listHeaderContainerView.backgroundColor=listHeaderContainerViewColor;
                [listHeaderContainerViewColor release];
                [listBGImagePath release];

                NSString *listBandPath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"listband_landscape" ofType:@"png"];
                UIImage *listBand=[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:listBandPath];
                self.categoryBrandingImageView.image=listBand;
                [listBand release];
            }
            self.bookInformation.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
            self.bookDescrption.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        }
    }
```

if any leaks is there please provide me the solution.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this part of code you have a mistake -

```
NSString *listBGImagePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"landscape_list_bg_nb" ofType:@"png"];
UIImage *listBGImage=[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:listBGImagePath];
UIColor *listHeaderContainerViewColor=[[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:listBGImage];
self.listHeaderContainerView.backgroundColor=listHeaderContainerViewColor;
[listHeaderContainerViewColor release];
[listBGImagePath release];
```

You have to release `listBGImage` instead of `listBGImagePath`